# Cells alignment in a vba created html outlook message

Tags: css, excel, vba, outlook

I have to generate an email every day and I have to copy excel cells to the e-mail (only two columns but many rows). I'm using this function:

```
str = "<table>"
str = str & "<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:" &  "collapse;}</style></head><body>"
getdata = str
```

I'm generating the email in this way:

```
With emailpod
    .BodyFormat = 3
    .display
    .To = Sheets("email").Range("H1").Value
    .cc = Sheets("email").Range("H2").Value
    .Subject = Sheets("email").Range("H3").Value & Sheets("email").Range("H6")
    .HTMLBody = Sheets("email").Range("H4") & "<br><br>" & Sheets("email").Range("H5") & "<br><br>" & _
        getdata & "<br>" & "Regards" & .HTMLBody & "</body>"

End With
```

I have borders for the cells but I also need align the cells to right inside the border. Any one knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style (CSS)

```
td {text-align:right;}
```

So it would look like this:

```
str = str & "<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse;} td {text-align:right;} </style></head><body>"
```